# How to take unique IDs of the following DISTINCT query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table:

```
id | description | URL    | role 
1  | desc_1      | url_1  | 1 
2  | desc_1      | url_1  | 2 
3  | desc_2      | url_2  | 1
4  | desc_2      | url_2  | 2
```

I want to get the following result

```
   id | description | URL 
   1  | desc_1      | url_1
   3  | desc_2      | url_2
```

I already tried this but to no avail

```
SELECT DISTINCT(description), id FROM table GROUP BY description
```

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function!!! It's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT` and works on the whole selected rows. Write `SELECT DISTINCT description, id` instead, to avoid confusion!!!

Comment: Also, you rarely never do SELECT DISTINCT and GROUP BY at the same time.

Comment: @jarlh That operation may not even be well defined, because often `DISTINCT` is itself implemented using `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(id),descritpion,URL GROUP BY description,URL

or 

SELECT MIN(id),descritpion,URL GROUP BY description,URL
```

depends if u want higher or lowest id.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT MIN(id)
    ,descritpion
    ,URL
FROM myTable
GROUP BY description
    ,URL
```

Comment: Forgot FROM part.

Answer (score 2):

Group By clause is generally used with aggregate functions. There are five aggregate functions in SQL. `MIN` , `MAX` , `COUNT` , `SUM` and `AVG`. In your situation you can use `MIN` or `MAX` functions to accomplish your work.

```
 select MIN(id),descritpion,URL from table GROUP BY description , URL
```

or

```
 select MAX(id),descritpion,URL from table GROUP BY description , URL
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t.id, t.description, t.URL
FROM
(
    SELECT id, description, URL,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY description, URL ORDER BY role) rn
    FROM yourTable
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Using MIN Clause to get result :

```
 SELECT MIN(id),description,URL
 FROM table GROUP BY description,URL
```